# Get value from data frame in r based on if/else statement and import to another data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

`df1 <- data.frame(AD=c(0,1,0,1), FN=c(101,202,105,104), var1=c(15,25,15,25), var2 = c(50,20,10,20))`

and I am trying to copy var1 or var2 based on the if statement. If AD == 0 take var1 and if AD ==1 take var2. It will be copied to the new column var and matched on FN? The output would look like this df `df2 <- data.frame(FN=c(101,202,105,104), var=c(15,20,15,20))`.

Answer (score 3):

```
df2 <- data.frame(FN = df1$FN, 
                  var = ifelse(df1$AD, df1$var2, df1$var1))
```

Comment: Can you combine match and ifelse?

Comment: I guess ifelse is hidden in match. Here ifelse is quite convenient.

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, please click the √ to accept it.